# iphone uitableview or uiscrollview better?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Regarding on negative commenst here I simplify my question in small steps

I have a view based application which communicates with a web service and recives xml, parse xml and map its contens an appropriate view component (e.g if thats a date show the question with datepicker, if question has 2 values show it with a segmented control, if more with a pickerview..etc) so its a dynamic questionary with many pages.

1-App Receive XML

2-Parse XML and get the latest un-answered questions (there can be unlimited number of questions per each page), each question need to be asked with either a textbox or picker view or segmented control depending on the question type, also it may need a few labels for explanition, and validation alerts, and the question label. Each question and label should have different fonts and colors, defined in xml.

3- User answers all questions inhe page and press send button.

4-Web service receives, checks the answers and sends back new question(s) to be asked depending on the answers given.

5-APP receives new XML (each XML includes whole the state i.e all the previous answered questions) and parse to find out the latest unanswered questions.

6-User again answers and sends the questions and wait for the next set of questions until there are no questions to be asked

7-OR user may want to go back and edit some questions in previous pages. BUT if he edits any question in previous pages then the pages answered after that page are not valid anymore, because each set of question server sends depends on the previosly answered questions, so it needs to delete all the later questions from XML and sends back a request as if it was the latest page waiting for a response.

Question:

1-Should I use UiScrollView or TableView? and what is the general object oriented design here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of them, depends on the scenario. The tableView offers a very good memory management model by default but with scrollView you need to manage memory yourself, managing means if you put so many UI elements on the scrollView, your app might start receiving memory warnings or in the worst case can get crashed. The reusability of table cells allows you to put much more content without overloading memory, provided if you use it sensibly. You just need to work on the custom tableView cells to get a view needed to display your questions.

Comment: tnx and what about using UINavigationController

Comment: ya NavigationController will help you a lot while coming back to the previous answers. It'll save the last state of your last questionView too. And when user resubmit the answers, you will resend the answers to the server and get new questions for the user, This way you'll automatically get the functionality of overwriting the answers of the question of the latest view as user now have to answer them again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `UINavigationController` and inside of each view in there, display all questions using a `UITableView` (i.e., push a `UITableViewController` on the navigation controller).

The navigation controller allows for representing in natural way the interaction you describe with your server and also allows to go back through the sets of questions (while also making not valid any pages after the one you go back to).

Comment: thanks, I checked UINavigationController, it looks like its used most in menus where there is a hieacrhy, my case there will be a bunch of questions in a page and a next and back button on bottom of page, do you think it is still the best choice?

Comment: and do I need to create a viewbased application or navigationbased application?

Comment: it's not only for hierarchy, but also for sequencing, like in a wizard, so I think it is ok. you need a navigation based app.

Comment: does this automatically support my step-7? browsing back capability? or do I need/should to parse xml eachtime for the necessary question set?

Comment: yes, it goes back automatically to previous view, no need to do anything special (the view is there, waiting for you to go back). if you have more questions about this, it is better if you collect them and modify your question; long comments are discouraged on S.O.

Answer (score 2):

If you want many questions in a list, and its an unknown number, you should defenitly use a tableview. Then you'll have much greater performance, and it will be easier to code.